# Continuous extension of a bounded linear operator in Fourier multiplier definition.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces

In $\mathbb{R}^n$.
For $1\leq p<\infty$  with $T:L^2\cap L^p\to L^p$  bounded linear operator, bounded in $L^p$. I know that it is possible to extend $T$ to $\bar{T}$ such that $T:L^p\to L^p$, bounded in $L^p$. This, by Bounded Linear Theorem.

My doubts are:
Is $L^p$  the completion of $L^2\cap L^p$? ($1\leq p<\infty)$

With $p=\infty$. Is it possible to extend the operator $T$? Or this fails?

I ask this because in Stein's 'Singular integral and differentiability properties', in fourier multiplier definition, a operator $T_m:L^2\cap L^p\to L^p$ is extended to $T_m:L^p\to L^p$ when $p<\infty$.

Comment: For any infinite measure space $L^{2} \cap L^{\infty}$ is not dense in $L^{\infty}$.

Comment: exists a counterexample?

Comment: On the real line you cannot approximate the constant function $1$ by an $L^{2}$ function w.r.t. $L{^\infty}$ norm because $\|1-g\|_{\infty} <\frac 1 2 $ implies $|g(x)| \geq \frac  1 2$ almost evreywhere.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can you please check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

> For $1 \le  <∞$,

$T : L^2 \cap L^p \to L^p$ bounded $\implies$ $T$ extends to a bounded linear operator $L^p \to L^p$ as $$_ ⊂ \operatorname \cap_{ q = 1}^\infty ^⊂^2∩^$$ and $_$ is dense in $L^p,\forall 1 \le p < \infty$.

> In case of $=∞$,

Note that $f \in ^2\cap ^\infty \implies ∈^,∀2≤≤∞$. Hence in order to find a bounded linear transformation $T : L^2 \cap L^\infty \to L^\infty$ that fails to extend as a bounded operator on $L^\infty$, combining with previous part, one basically has to produce a linear transformation that will extend to a bounded linear transformation from $^→^∞,∀2≤<∞$ but fail to be Bounded when $^∞→^∞$.

What can be more natural than convolution operators? For any $f \in L^p(\Bbb R^n), g \in L^q(\Bbb R^n) $ we have from [Young's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality) $$||f*g||_r \le ||f||_p ||g||_q \text{ where }  \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1+\frac{1}{r} \text{ and } 1\le p,q \le r \le \infty$$

**Comment: Moreover, for a fixed $q,r$ in the above relations, you can show by doing a bit of Dimensional analysis ( i.e. dilating the functions ) that $p$ is indeed the unique choice.**

So just choose a function $g \in L^q(\Bbb R^n), \forall 1 < q \le 2$ but $g \notin L^1(\Bbb R^n)$ say $g(x)=\frac{1}{||x||} \Bbb{1}_{\{x \in \Bbb R^n: ||x||>1\}}$

Now define the transformation $T_g : L^2 \cap L^\infty \to L^\infty$ by $T_g(f):= f*g $, then by Young's inequality and the adjacent comment, it follows that $T_g$ is indeed a linear transformation with the desired properties i.e. Bounded from $L^2 \cap L^\infty \to L^\infty$ but does not extend to a Bounded operator on $L^\infty$